# Including google font in my project

Tags: html, css, google-font-api

I included Montserrat-Regular in my project. But its not detecting and font style is not changing.

In my `index.html:`

I included the fonts URL too.

```
<link href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

css:

```
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);

    @font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Montserrat Regular'), local('Montserrat-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v10/SKK6Nusyv8QPNMtI4j9J2yEAvth_LlrfE80CYdSH47w.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
```

Comment: can you share live link for your working code? or try Codepen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to put the link in your HTML file :

`<link href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

and then use it on every element you want in your **CSS file**:

`p {
   font-family: 'Montserrat';
}`

**Check this fiddle for a better example: https://jsfiddle.net/vf7q1gjy/1/**

Comment: Thank you. Its really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Set the font family in your CSS file:

```
body { font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; }
```